# Polynomial addition using linked lists (theory only)

Tags: polynomials

Someone on Stackoverflow suggested posting here.

I have an Algorithms test coming up for my Software Engineering course, but the book and lecture notes don't explain the theory behind summing polynomials using linked lists (No joke, they really don't).

Can anyone explain simply the theory using any example they want? 
Thanks in advance.